In Django Admin, adding a model as a tab
I am trying to sort out my admin site for my django application. I have a lorcana_sets table and a lorcana_sets_cards table. lorcana_sets_cards has a foreign key to lorcana_sets via set_id field.
If I add the follow:
# Lorcana Sets - Cards
class LorcanaSetsCards(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
    list_display_links = ['name']

admin.site.register(lorcana_sets_cards, LorcanaSetsCards)

I get a table that lists all the cards and I can click on the name of the card in the list and be taken to the card object where I am able to edit that card object's fields.
Now I have created the following where I have the table of sets and when I click into the set object there is a Lorcana Cards tab that contains a table which lists all of the cards in that set.
class LorcanaSetsCardsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = lorcana_sets_cards
    extra = 0
    fields = ['id', 'number', 'full_name', 'hidden', 'manual']
    readonly_fields = ['id', 'number', 'full_name']

    @admin.display(description='Name')
    def full_name(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.name} - {obj.subtitle}" if obj.subtitle else obj.name

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(number_as_int=Cast('number', output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('number_as_int')
        return qs

# Lorcana Sets
class LorcanaSets(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['code', 'name', 'type', 'release_date']
    list_display_links = ['name']
    search_fields = ['code', 'name', 'type']
    ordering = ['-release_date']

    inlines = [LorcanaSetsCardsInline,]

admin.site.register(lorcana_sets, LorcanaSets)

I would like this table to have a link similar to class LorcanaSetsCards(admin.ModelAdmin): where I can click and be taken to that cards objects to edit any fields I need.
I am not sure if this is possible or not. I am currently using Django==4.2.11.

So I managed to work it out. I have the Lorcana Set Admin Model:
# Lorcana Sets
class LorcanaSets(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['code', 'name', 'type', 'release_date']
    list_display_links = ['name']
    search_fields = ['code', 'name', 'type']
    ordering = ['-release_date']

    inlines = [LorcanaSetsCardsInline,]

admin.site.register(lorcana_sets, LorcanaSets)

I created the Lorcana Card Admin Model, however I have removed it from the side navigation bar, so the user has to go to a set and then to the Lorcana Card tab. I also change the "save" functionality to bring the user back to the Lorcana Card tab on the Lorcana Set object when clicked:
# Lorcana Sets - Cards
class LorcanaSetsCardsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # This removes it from the side navigation bar
    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return False

    # This changes the "save" functionality to go to the Lorcana Sets object the user was previously on.
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if "_continue" not in request.POST and "_addanother" not in request.POST and "_saveasnew" not in request.POST:
            set_id = getattr(obj, 'set_id', None)  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'../../../lorcana_sets/{set_id}/change/#lorcana-cards-tab')
        else:
            return super().response_change(request, obj)

admin.site.register(lorcana_sets_cards, LorcanaSetsCardsAdmin)


and the inline Lorcana Cards Admin Model. This is to display the the list of Lorcana Cards on the Lorcana Set object:
class LorcanaSetsCardsInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = lorcana_sets_cards
    extra = 0
    fields = ['number', 'full_name_link', 'manual', 'hidden']
    readonly_fields = ['number', 'full_name_link']

    # Changed the cell to be a link to the Lorcana Card object
    @admin.display(description='Name')
    def full_name_link(self, obj):
        if obj.pk is not None and obj.pk != '':
            url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.model_name), args=[obj.pk])
            return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, self.full_name(obj))
        else:
            return self.full_name(obj)

    def full_name(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.name} - {obj.subtitle}" if obj.subtitle else obj.name

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(number_as_int=Cast('number', output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('number_as_int')
        return qs

    full_name_link.allow_tags = True

